# Fitnesse Acceptance test tool : how to tell fitnesse to not omit the space characters

Tags: kotlin, fitnesse

i am writing test fixtures with kotlin language , and as you know you can have space characters in the class name and even the functions name using the back ticks

i am writing the tables  using Persian language and when the Fitneese tries to find  the class or function , it just removes all the spaces and looks for the target.so in order to make classes and functions available to Fitnesse , i have to concat all the words , and it just reads nonsense in the fixture class when using persian.

i am looking for a way to tell the fitnesse , disable its removing space mechanism

i have tried putting underline between words , and it just looks awful but works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to change FitNesse's behaviour in this respect, out of the box.

What you could try is creating a custom 'interaction' class (subclass of `fitnesse.slim.fixtureInteraction.DefaultInteraction`) that resolves classes and methods/functions in a different way.

In the wiki you can indicate that your custom interaction should be used instead of `DefaultInteraction` in your suite's root page, `!define slim.flags {-i your.package.YourOwnInteraction}`

Comment: thanks , i tried it and i think you have put me on the write track , when i subclass it and give it to the slim engine the way you said , it is successfully replaced and all the interactions are being passed through mine.

but the names of methods are already changed when it is passed to for example findMatchingMethod method.

we must track down the guy who calls this interaction and try to replace that.cause thats one in lead

Comment: this solution works when you are writing the things in English , cause that way , when your default interaction implementation is being asked for the class or method , you can extract the words based on the first upper case letter and then you can also search for the method or a class whit a name having space in between.but when you are writing the scenarios in any language other than english , then there wont be any sign for you to recognize the words one by one and they are concatanated in a not meaningful way

Answer (score 0):

according to @Fried Hoeben  solution i implemented my own default interaction class which first removes the spaces of all the names of the methods of the class and then it checks it against the coming method name from Fitnesse which is already decorated and its spaces has been removed

this solution works for methods , but for class matching , when you override searchPathForClass , you have to get all the class which have been loaded through the class loader and decorate their names which is too much and slow

so use it for method matching not class matching :

```
class MyDefaultInteraction: DefaultInteraction() {

    override fun findMatchingMethod(methodName: String, instance: Any, vararg args: Any?): Method? {

        instance.javaClass.methods.forEach {

            if(doMethodMatchWithGivenMethodNameAndArguments(it,methodName,args))
                return it
        }


        return super.findMatchingMethod(methodName, instance, *args)
    }


    private fun doMethodMatchWithGivenMethodNameAndArguments(method: Method, givenMethodName: String, args: Array<out Any?>)=
       (decorateMethodNameToBeMatchCandidate(givenMethodName) == decorateMethodNameToBeMatchCandidate(method.name) && doArgsMatch(method, args))


    private fun decorateMethodNameToBeMatchCandidate(name:String) =  name.replace(" ", "")
            .replace(",", "").toLowerCase()

    private fun doArgsMatch(method: Method, args: Array<out Any?>) = method.parameterTypes.size == args.size

}
```